# How do I combine my ajax request into one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am successfully looping my data with ajax but when I console log I see my data sent in a new line.

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  $.get(settings).then(data => makeTable(data.contracts))
  const makeTable = (contracts) => {
      const body = document.getElementById('chart');
      contracts.forEach((person, index) => {
        person.details.forEach((entry) => {
          const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(entry.hours), Number);
          chart.updateSeries([{
            name: 'Hours',
            data: [entry.hours]
          }])

          console.log(arrayOfDigits)
```

I also tried converting my integers into an object but it would come out as

```
[integer]
[integer]
[integer]
[integer]
[integer]
```

But what I would like to do is having it in the same object like so

```
[integer, integer, integer, integer]
```

Comment: The answer is not clear, what do want to get? You are doing console.log in foreach loop, that a reason why you have values in a new line. You can save all values in array and do a console log after the loop.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer into the question.

Comment: Sorry very new to asking questions in stack overflow I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Push `arrayOfDigits` into an array and log that at the end, rather than logging each one separately.

```
const makeTable = (contracts) => {
  const body = document.getElementById('chart');
  const result = [];
  contracts.forEach((person, index) => {
    person.details.forEach((entry) => {
      const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(entry.hours), Number);
      chart.updateSeries([{
        name: 'Hours',
        data: [entry.hours]
      }])
      result.push(arrayOfDigits);
    });
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing so but it would come back as undefined.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to log outside the `makeTable` function, before the AJAX request has completed.

Comment: Yes! I was logging in the wrong place!! Thank you for pointing it out! I changed my code with the addition of your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Final code working as intended:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $.get(settings).then(data => makeTable(data.contracts))
    const makeTable = (contracts) => {
        const body = document.getElementById('chart');
        const result = [];
        contracts.forEach((person, index) => {
            person.details.forEach((entry) => {
                result.push(entry.hours);
            });  
        }); 
    chart.updateSeries([{
            name: 'Hours',
            data: [result]
      }])
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```